# Drag and Drop ListBox for WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox

I'm looking for just a simple `ListBox` with build-in Drag & Drop. I think that Silverlight 4 Toolkit has [something like that](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL4DragDropListBox.aspx?pageflow=Fluid&fid=1572066&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick).

The `BoxList` should be able to:

- reorder by dragging & dropping items
- drag item from one `BoxList` to another
- display preview (ghost version) of dragged item
- show drop location (like a line between items where the dragged will be inserted)

I hope there is some solution from microsoft (in toolkit for example), but if not I all be happy with any working solution. For example I wander what control was used in DataGrid column headers reordering (by dragging and dropping them) implementation.

Thank you for any suggestions

**EDIT:** Please do not suggest commercial controls. This is not for a commercial project and I don't want to buy it. Thank you

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so could you please tell us how, thanks

Comment: There are some examples how to do this on the internet but they are little outdated (still working with latest .NET). Hovewer no solution really suits my needs, so I'm going to implement the logic myself and use adorment layer to display ghost image of dragged item.

Answer (score 0):

The build in ListBox can implement drag and drop, you just have to handle the drag and drop operations.

I use the [going-wpf-dragdrop](http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/) library

It also contains examples of using it within a WPF application