# WPF - Drag'n'drop DataTemplate in listbox up and down

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have sophisticated data template of the item in listbox similar to [this](http://www.wpftutorial.net/images/listbox_datatemplate3.png)
I need to click anywhere inside this item and drag it up or down in the list. 
Maybe somebody has already implemented such functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350187/wpf-c-rearrange-items-in-listbox-via-drag-and-drop and this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704358/drag-and-drop-listbox-for-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good [example](http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html) for  for drag and drop. There are some bugs in code but you can find their solutions in the comment area.

Comment: Here's another example i made a sample application that you will find usefull in which you can actually see what item is dragged with mouse pointer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691041/how-to-implement-single-item-dragdrop-wpf-listview-in-mvvm-way/7691199#7691199

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Bea Stollnitz has and the code is posted [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53)