# How to implement single item DragDrop WPF Listview in MVVM way?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I have two listviews (and Gridview inside that) inmy WPF/MVVM application. How would I implement Drag/Drop for single item in this case?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have made a sample application where you can have an idea about how it works with the MVVM i have ItemsControl ListView and another Listview Where you can drag and drop single item. 
you can find it [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=d8443a8832e1fdf8&id=D8443A8832E1FDF8%21137) a project named DragDropItems Credit [Bea Stollnitz's](https://web.archive.org/web/20151107025019/http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488)

Comment: I am unable to get the source code. I dont know why it is so.

Comment: I have edited the link there you will find a project DragDropItems

Comment: this is the best code i found yet. No tons of interfaces etc , it does the work :)

Comment: @NividDholakia the link is dead :(

Comment: @NividDholakia It looks like your DragDrop code was taken from Bea Stollnitz's blog (http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.VSeTIJONvMs), and there are no references at all in the source code. 
You make it seem as though you have written the code yourself. Could you indicate where the code came from, please?

Comment: Why not just put the relevant code parts here directly ? Your answer would be way more useful that way.

Answer (score 3):

Usually for DragDrop I use the code found at [Bea Stollnitz's Blog](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53). It's simple, easy to understand, and easy to modify as needed.

Comment: The linked page seems to have been moved to a new site - but the new site is also down. Here's an archived version of the blog post: https://web.archive.org/web/20151107025019/http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488