# How to drag all the selected items from a listview to another listview

Tags: c#, wpf

The below is my code,

```
    ListView sourcelistview = null;
    ListView targetlistview = null;
    Point startPoint;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbOne.Items.Add("xxxx");
        lbOne.Items.Add("yyyy");
        lbOne.Items.Add("zzzz");
        lbOne.Items.Add("uuuu"); 
        lbOne.Items.Add("vvvv");
        lbOne.Items.Add("wwww"); 
        lbOne.Items.Add("rrrr");
        lbOne.Items.Add("ssss");
    }

    private void lbOne_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    }

    private void lbTwo_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

        targetlistview = (ListView)sender;
            var Sourcedata = sourcelistview.SelectedItems.Cast<object>().ToArray();
            foreach (string item in Sourcedata)
            {
                targetlistview.Items.Add(item);
                sourcelistview.Items.Remove(item);
            }            
    }        

    private void lbOne_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {           
        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
        {
            {
                sourcelistview = (ListView)sender;
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(sourcelistview, sourcelistview.SelectedItems.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }            
        }      
    }
```

This works for single event drag, but when I attempt to drag multiple events, the last item I select gets deselected and other items are moved.
Any solution for this?

Regards,
RV

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you press the left mouse button it deselects the last entry.

As a cheap quick hack, you could do this:

```
private List<object> _selItems = new List<object>();    
private void lbOne_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    _selItems.Clear();
    _selItems.AddRange(((ListView)sender).SelectedItems.Cast<object>());
}
```

And on `MouseMove`:

```
private void lbOne_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    /* ... */
    sourcelistview = (ListView)sender;

    foreach (object selItem in _selItems)
    {
        if (!sourcelistview.SelectedItems.Contains(selItem))
            sourcelistview.SelectedItems.Add(selItem);
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time... There are no ItemDrag events in WPF, thats our concern, your code works in winforms... Help us in WPF

Comment: I see, I'll tag your question

Comment: You should check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530334/how-to-do-drag-and-drop-in-wpf-between-two-lists)

Comment: @RajaVignesh I've written a quick hack that works (I just tried it), however you should check the question I linked to. This is just not the correct way to do things in WPF :-)